# batch file need to gather information on remote machine - windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

Scenario: MachineA,B & C in a network, I need to run a batch file to gather information and list all the files in a folder under each machine.

Can I run the batch file from MachineA and collect the information from B&C.

Server:Windows

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553). Run the following on MachineA:

```
psexec.exe \\MachineB dir "C:\test" /AD
```

Or, map network drives to the machines and list them through the drive mappings.